# How many countries have recognized Taiwan as a sovereign nation?

Tags: international-relations, taiwan

[Today, only 14 countries recognize Taiwan.](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2021/12/1/china-hunts-taiwan-nationals-through-forced-deportation-report)

What's the maximum number of countries that recognized Taiwan at any given time?

Comment: By "Taiwan", do you mean "Republic of China".  Would recognition of the RoC while it was the principle government of China, count?  What about the period 1921-1949?

Comment: No, I mean Taiwan - the country located on the island

Comment: @JoeJobs The official name of that country is [Republic of China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_of_China) and to some extent and to very recent times to a complete extent it claims(ed) to be the only legitimate government of the single unified China, just like the communist government in Peking, not a separate island country. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_status_of_Taiwan Be aware that this status is also enforced by the communist government in Peking because it threatens by an invasion if Taiwan declares independence from China.

Comment: The consequence is that it is hard for other countries to recognize an independent country of Taiwan, when the country does not declare independence in the first place. Recognizing the Taipei government as the legitimate government of the single China then makes the communist government in Peking illegitimate.

Comment: btw: a great many people are aware that Taiwan is a country even if there is no official document saying so

Comment: What is now colloquially known as "Taiwan" was the single government of China for a long time. Even after the KMT government was driven to Taiwan the island, most countries still recognized it as the single Chinese government. Only after United Nations General Assembly Resolution 2758 passed in 1971 did the situation drastically change. A WP summary: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_General_Assembly_Resolution_2758 It was a really interesting and important event in hindsight.

Comment: It would not be surprising that you have the impression "No, I mean Taiwan - the country located on the island" since all across the mainstream western media the fact that the government is literally called "Republic of China" has been systematically omitted/suppressed for a fairly long time to create the support for Taiwan as independent from the mainland, and practically no common westerner of this generation seems to even be aware of the actual history of what went down. Good that this question was asked so that one may read up on this.

Comment: When it comes to "recognition" by other countries, you can only talk about the government. The "country", the "nation", the "people", the "land", the whatever it is other than the government cannot be 'recognized' in a diplomatic sense. The government is called "Republic of China". It is a government that started off owning different land and governing different people. It is a government imposed on the people of Taiwan but one they now democratically control. If you want to ask about formal diplomatic recognition, that's what you have to ask about.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Wikipedia has a table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_relations_of_Taiwan#History) showing the number of countries recognising the Republic of China (ROC, modern-day Taiwan) and the People's Republic of China (PRC, modern-day China) respectively.

> **Number of countries recognising ROC and PRC**
>
> | Year | Recognition of ROC[<sup>[115]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_relations_of_Taiwan#cite_note-117) | Recognition of PRC |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1969 | 71 | 48 |
> | 1971 | 68 | 53 |
> | 1973 | 31 | 89 |
> | 1978 | 21 | 112 |
> | 1986 | 23 | 134 |
> | 1990 | 28 | 139 |
> | 2012 | 23 | 172 |
> | 2013 | 22 | 172 |
> | 2016 | 21 | 174 |
> | 2017 | 20 | 175 |
> | 2018 | 17 | 178 |
> | 2019 | 15 | 180 |
> | 2021 | 14 | 181[<sup>[note 3]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_relations_of_Taiwan#cite_note-118) |

And here's a [timeline of diplomatic relations of the Republic of China from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_diplomatic_relations_of_the_Republic_of_China).

It's worth noting that the United Nations switched recognition from the ROC to the PRC in 1971 and before that, most countries recognised the ROC as the legitimate government of China, explaining the large number of diplomatic recognitions of the ROC then.

Comment: the balance changed between 1971 and 1973. What events could have impacted the drastic swing of the international political pendulum within those 2 years?

Comment: @lurscher In short, PRC had a fallout with the Soviet Union, and the Nixon government thought it might be wise to try to win PRC over or at least pull it away from the Soviet Union as much as possible. This was an important catalyst of the switching of the recognition in the UN from ROC to PRC (of course there were also other factors). Now the US might lament it as a huge mistake, though it was an important turning point for PRC to later naturally assert itself as an important international power ("China" has a seat in the security council, and with the switch it naturally fell to PRC)

Comment: It was a really interesting event. There's a WP page for summary https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_General_Assembly_Resolution_2758 and surely there're many more detailed accounts. Now the US doesn't want to talk about it much, in part because it was such a blatant betrayal of an ally... (the ROC representative literally walked out of the UN venue in protest), which it did a lot anyways, especially during that time. (Though to be fair the US also didn't expect the situation to come to a complete expulsion of ROC, as it supported a less radical motion than what was passed in the end)

Comment: @wji is hard not to think that the stereotype of republicans being appeasers has a long tradition

Comment: Some important context missing from this answer is that the "Republic of China" and the "People's Republic of China" *are the same country*.  They're different governments, but (at least in theory) lay claim to the same territory.